# How to get the actual Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, findviewbyid

Maybe this is the dumbest question ever, but I'm having a little trouble getting the actual `Activity` object.

My purpose:

In order to extract error handling from the different `Activity`s, I made a class `ErrorHandler` with static methods.

Such a method looks like this for example:

```
public class ErrorHandler {
    ...
    public static ErrorTuple checkPlaceInput(Activity activity){
        EditText edit = (EditText) activity.findViewById(R.id.et_nbge_place);
        if(edit.getText().toString().equals("") || edit.getText()==null){
            return new ErrorTuple(false, "Please enter a place!");
        }
        return new ErrorTuple(true, "everything is fine");
    }
}
```

In order to access the `findViewById(...)` method, I have to pass the `Activity` as parameter. As I read in different questions here, there is no other way to access `View`s from outside a running `Activity`. But, from the `Activity` itself, how can I access this object? Neither the `Context` nor the `MyActivity.class` are exactly the `Activity` object.

Comment: What makes you think that using 'this' in the Activity class doesn't reference that Activity?.

Comment: Because I thought using this referrs to the Context, and I thought Context != Activity. So my question was dumb indeed :-/

Comment: @Daniel That's a little short sighted. `this` refers to the container object. For instance, using `this` inside an anonymous class in an Activity, like `new OnClickListener() {...}`, won't reference the Activity class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're calling that method from an Activity, just do `checkPlaceInput( this )`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html) to get the current object. Inside an Activity, you can just call findViewByID without anything before.

Answer (score 0):

Use `this.` keyword - it is your object instance. And within Activity scope you can just call `findViewById()` directly